# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined, i need some help here

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function loadCommands(client) {
    fs.readdir('commands/', (err, files) => {        

        if (err) console.log(err);
    
        const jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'js');
        if (jsfile.length <= 0) {
            return console.log('Bot Couldn\'t Find Commands in commands Folder.');
        }
    
        jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
            const pull = require(`../commands/${f}`);
            client.commands.set(pull.config.name, pull);
            pull.config.aliases.forEach(alias => {
                bot.aliases.set(alias, pull.config.name);
            });
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    loadCommands
}
```

I don't know why the error it's here it looks great the code...

> The error is found in **client.commands.set(pull.config.name, pull);** and in **bot.aliases.set(alias, pull.config.name);** show that is undefined.

I need some help here, i'm trying to make a custom prefix for my bot and I really need this code!

[The error in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSetG.png)

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong; i.e. `pull.config` is `undefined`. Either fix the files to have an object with a config key, or check for undefined in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the files in `../commands/whateverFile.js` doesn't export `config`, or does export `config` but doesn't put a `.name` property on it. You didn't show us any of those files so it's hard to guess at the problem.

You could try this to figure out which file is bad.

```js
        jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
            const pull = require(`../commands/${f}`);
            if (!pull || !pull.config || !pull.config.name) {
                throw new Error (`bogus require file ${f}`)
            }
            client.commands.set(pull.config.name, pull);
            pull.config.aliases.forEach(alias => {
                bot.aliases.set(alias, pull.config.name);
            });
        });
```